# Mongo query to get children

Tags: mongodb, syntax, fluent, fluent-mongo

I am using fluent mongo.

I have an entity as

```
public class SomeList
{
        public List<ItemLike> Likes { get; set; }
        public List<ItemComment> Comments { get; set; }
        public List<ListItem> ListItems { get; set; }
}
```

the ListItem is another entity

```
public class ListItem 
{
        pub string ListItemId { get; set; }
        public List<ItemComment> CommentsList { get; set; }
        public List<Photo> ItemPhotos { get; set; }
}
```

So the main entity SomeList has List and also the entity ListItem has List.

I want a mongo query to get the List from ListItem.

I am using a following query

```
var myCollection = GetMongoDatabase().GetCollection<SomeList>("SomeLists");
var list = myCollection.Find(Query.EQ("ListItems.ListItemId", listItemId)).SetFields(Fields.Slice("ListItems.LikesList", 0)).SingleOrDefault();

ListItem listItem = list.ListItems.Where(x => x.ListItemId == listItemId).SingleOrDefault();
items = listItem.CommentsList;
```

When I do Query.EQ(“ListItems.ListItemId”, listItemId), it gives the main SomeList entity.
I am again applying where clause in the next line. Which i don't want.

Answer (score 1):

So you are geting the main SomeList collection returned in list here?

```
var list = myCollection.Find(Query.EQ("ListItems.ListItemId", listItemId))
             .SetFields(Fields.Slice("ListItems.LikesList", 0)).SingleOrDefault();
```

What do you get if you remove the `SingleOrDefault()` call from this?

Comment: Even then it gives the main entity.

Comment: What is returned if you remove the slice? `var list = myCollection.Find(Query.EQ("ListItems.ListItemId",listItemId));`
What are you getting back - is this query working as expected?